# Wedding after a death in the family in the Eastern Orthodox Church

Tags: eastern-orthodox, marriage, death

Does the Eastern Orthodox Church say anything on festivities after the death of a member of the family? Specifically weddings in the 40 days after the death when mourning is called for?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for your question.  As written, your question was quite broad, since there are many Christian churches.  If you'd like to ask for the view of another group besides Eastern Orthodox, please ask a separate question.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Could you explain more what this "wedding" after (physical) death is? Where (if) is it done and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Orthodox weddings are prohibited on *at least* the following days:

- Great Lent (variable)
- Holy Week (variable)
- Pascha (variable)
- Pentecost (variable)
- The Apostle's Fast (variable-June 29)
- The Dormition Fast (August 1-15)
- The Beheading of St. John the Baptist (August 29)
- Exaltation of the Holy Cross (September 14)
- Nativity Fast (November 14-December 25, or until January 7, depending on calendar)
- Theophany (January 6)

Some parishes or jurisdictions may also not permit marriages on [Saturdays](https://saintseraphim.com/marriage) or [in the evening before Wednesdays and Fridays](https://www.dneoca.org/guidelines_marriage).

There are no restrictions about marrying after the death of someone in the family.